# Proportionally split a field across rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a field that is doubling a value by populating it in both rows for the date/location/product/company id. The lost Sales is coming through into both rows, but it is actually the total for both. I need to remove the duplicate and proportionally split it across the rows to make the New Lost Sales column

New Lost Sales = (row omits / sum omits on all rows) * Lost Sales on row

| Date | Location | Product | CompanyID | Omits | Lost_Sales | New_Lost_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/9 | Loc1 | Prod1 | A | 0 | 50 | 0 |
| 1/9 | Loc1 | Prod1 | B | 40 | 50 | 50 |
| 1/9 | Loc2 | Prod1 | A | 8 | 40 | 16 |
| 1/9 | Loc2 | Prod1 | B | 12 | 40 | 24 |

Comment: Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's much more likely people will be able to help you if you follow these guidelines.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

Comment: I've removed the tag [[tag:azure]] as well, as I can't see how that is relevant.

Comment: You have the logic you need here, so what is the problem/difficulty you are having implementing it?

Comment: You can use `COUNT() OVER(PARTITION BY Date,Loc1, ???)` to get the count for a specific combination of keys and divide by that. Or you can use `SUM(Omits) OVER (...)` to get the total of Omits, eg `lost_sales*omits/SUM(Omits) OVER (...)`. Without more information it's hard to say what keys should be used or what the strategy should be

Comment: You can't do it :) You might think it works, but it doesn't, the only way is to fix your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Lost_Sales is recorded per date and location *only*, you can use `SUM(Omits) OVER (Date,Location)` to calculate the sum of omits for each key combination.

For example

```
Select 
    1.00*lost_sales*omits/SUM(Omits) OVER (Date,Location) As New_Lost_Sales
FROM
...
```

You may have to adjust the query in case `SUM(Omits)` can be null or `0`, eg `SUM(ISNULL(Omits,0))`.

Without the actual tables and sample data one can only make guesses. What happens for example if `SUM(Omits)` is 0 but `Lost_Sales` isn't? Are fractional lost sales acceptable?

Let's say you want to retain `Lost_Sales` if `SUM(INSULL(Omits,0))` is 0. To avoid repeating the SUM clause, you can use a CTE to calculate it once and use it in an IIF clause:

```
WITH omits as (
    Select 
        ...,
        SUM(Omits) OVER (Date,Location) as TotalOmits
    FROM
    ...
)
select *,
    IIF(TotalOmits=0,
        Lost_Sales,
        1.00*lost_sales*omits/TotalOmits) as New_Lost_Sales
FROM omits
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    Date,
    Location,
    Product,
    CompanyID,
    SUM(Omits) AS TotalOmits
  FROM YourTableName 
  GROUP BY Date, Location, Product, CompanyID
)

SELECT
  t.Date,
  t.Location,
  t.Product,
  t.CompanyID,
  t.Omits,
  t.Lost_Sales,
  (t.Omits * 1.0 / c.TotalOmits) * t.Lost_Sales AS New_Lost_Sales
FROM YourTableName t 
JOIN CTE c
  ON t.Date = c.Date
  AND t.Location = c.Location
  AND t.Product = c.Product
  AND t.CompanyID = c.CompanyID;
```